# Problems with feed import

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I can't load a csv file to a content type. It was so easy with D6 and node import, but with [feed import module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) I'm getting crazy.
My content type has the next fields:

```
title (from content type itself)  
original_title (text field)  
image (image field)  
description (body)  
year (integer)  
preview_date (date)  
duration (integer)  
country (country)  
director (multi-term reference vocabulary Directors)  
actor (multi-term reference vocabulary Actor)  
music (text field)  
photo (text field)  
producer (text field)  
web  (url)  
genero (multi-term reference vocabulary Generos)
premios (text area)
val1 (five star ratings)  
val2 (five star ratings)  
trailer (youtube video field)
```

None of them are requiered (except title, obviously). This is a sample of the csv file I want to upload.

```
"1";"(500) Días Juntos";"(500) Days Of Summer";"El protagonista de la película es Gordon-Lewit (Tom), un joven que se enamora perdidamente de una chica (Zooey Deschanel). Lamentablemente para él, ella no cree en el amor... Presentada en Sundance 2009, 500 días juntos es la película indi sorpresa del 2009, una ópera prima de un conocido director de videos musicales que consiguió más de 30 millones de dólares de recaudación.";"Estados Unidos";"95";"2009";"Marc Webb";"Joseph Gordon-Levitt,|Zooey Deschanel|Geoffrey Arend|Chloe Grace Moretz|Matthew Gray Gubler";"www.youtube.com/v/JZKHghwE0CM&hl";"";"2015-11-01 01:01:01";"pel_1268042400_zzz.jpg";"Sin catalogar";"Fox"
"2";"¡A Lo Grande!";"Large";"Jason Mouseley es un joven de Biramingham que vive una absurda existencia. Marcado por la muerte de su padre Barry &quot;Blaze&quot; Mouseley, una leyenda del rock, una madrastra paranoica y unos indeseables amigos que dedican todo su tiempo a preparar juergas, la vida de Jason se mueve entre locas fiestas, movidas y alcohol. Pero a punto de cumplir los dieciocho a Jason se la plantea un gran problema.";"Reino Unido";"80";"2001";"Justin Edgar";"Luke De Woolfson - Jason Melanie Gutteridge - Sophie Simon Lowe - Rob Lee Oakes - Ian Mirren Delaney - Lisa Gate";"";"";"2006-07-15 00:00:00";"A LO GRANDE.jpg";"Sin catalogar";""
"3";"¡Ay, Carmela!";"¡Ay, Carmela!";"Guerra Civil española (1936-1939). Un grupo de cómicos ameniza como puede la vida de los soldados republicanos; pero, cansados de pasar penalidades en el frente, se dirigen a Valencia. Por error, van a parar a la zona nacional, donde caen prisioneros. La única manera de salvar sus vidas es representar un espectáculo para un grupo de militares, que choca de lleno con la ideología de los cómicos.";"España";"100";"1990";"Carlos Saura";"Carmen Maura|Andrés Pajares|Gabino Diego|Armando De Razza|Miguel Rellán";"";"";"2015-11-01 01:01:01";"pel_1103478448_zzz.jpg";"Sin catalogar";""
"4";"¡Bienvenido, Míster Marshall!";"¡Bienvenido, Míster Marshall!";"Villar del Río es un pueblo pequeño, tranquilo, pobre y olvidado, en el que nunca pasa nada que se salga de la rutina. Sólo la llegada de la cantante folclórica Carmen Vargas y de Manolo, su apoderado y representante, ha supuesto una novedad en la aburrida vida del pueblo. Sin embargo, ese mismo día se presenta de pronto un delegado gubernativo que anuncia que, de un momento a otro, va a llegar una comisión del Plan Marshall (proyecto económico americano para la reconstrucción de Europa). El alcalde del pueblo, un hombre bonachón, decide entonces que toda la población se disfrace al más puro estilo andaluz para causar buena impresión a los visitantes que vienen a repartir dinero.";"España";"75";"1952";"Luis García Berlanga";"José Isbert|Lolita Sevilla|Manolo Morán|Alberto Romea|Elvira Quintillá";"";"";"2015-11-01 01:01:01";"pel_1000066371_zzz.jpg";"Sin catalogar";"Tribanda Pictures"
```

My mapping field template is:

```
guid;title;original_title;descrition;country;duration;year;director;actor;trailer;web;preview_date;image;genero;producer
```

I have tried with double quotes and without it. I haver revised the mapping fields and I use [feed tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to import multi-value term reference (separated with |).
When I import It, It only creates a one blank node.
Where could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Edited: feed importer

```
 $feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default feeds_importer disabled initially */
$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'peliculas';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
  'name' => 'Películas',
  'description' => 'Importar csv de películas',
  'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsFileFetcher',
    'config' => array(
      'allowed_extensions' => 'txt csv tsv xml opml',
      'direct' => 0,
      'directory' => 'public://feeds',
      'allowed_schemes' => array(
        'public' => 'public',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsCSVParser',
    'config' => array(
      'delimiter' => ';',
      'no_headers' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'processor' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
    'config' => array(
      'expire' => '-1',
      'author' => '50',
      'authorize' => 0,
      'mappings' => array(
        0 => array(
          'source' => 'title',
          'target' => 'title',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        1 => array(
          'source' => 'titulo',
          'target' => 'field_titulo_original',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        2 => array(
          'source' => 'Sinopsis',
          'target' => 'body',
          'format' => 'full_html',
        ),
        3 => array(
          'source' => 'Pais',
          'target' => 'node:pel_cula:field_pa_s:name',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        4 => array(
          'source' => 'Duracion',
          'target' => 'field_duracion',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        5 => array(
          'source' => 'Año',
          'target' => 'field_anno',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        6 => array(
          'source' => 'Director',
          'target' => 'field_director',
          'term_search' => '0',
          'autocreate' => 1,
        ),
        7 => array(
          'source' => 'Reparto',
          'target' => 'field_reparto',
          'term_search' => '0',
          'autocreate' => 1,
        ),
        8 => array(
          'source' => 'Trailer',
          'target' => 'field_trailer',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        9 => array(
          'source' => 'Web oficial',
          'target' => 'url',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        10 => array(
          'source' => 'Fecha estreno',
          'target' => 'field_fecha_de_estreno_en_video:start',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        11 => array(
          'source' => 'Caratula',
          'target' => 'field_caratula:uri',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        12 => array(
          'source' => 'Género',
          'target' => 'field_g_nero',
          'term_search' => '0',
          'autocreate' => 1,
        ),
        13 => array(
          'source' => 'Productora',
          'target' => 'field_productora',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        14 => array(
          'source' => 'Guid',
          'target' => 'guid',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
      ),
      'update_existing' => '0',
      'update_non_existent' => 'skip',
      'input_format' => 'plain_text',
      'skip_hash_check' => 0,
      'bundle' => 'pel_cula',
    ),
  ),
  'content_type' => '',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '-1',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 0,
);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in watchdog? Can you find and enable debug messages in Feeds?

Comment: Feed log shows nothing. Only one node imported. Watchdog: Notice: Undefined index: rating en entity_metadata_field_property_get() . But ratings fields are not required, and I are not available on mapping fields configuration.

Comment: How do you import it? At `/import`? There is an option to debug each field, you already tried activating it?

Comment: Yes. I use /import to do it. I haven't found how to debug it. There is a module "Debugging Feeds" but I don't know how to get the tar ball to install it.

Comment: It's probably worth to export your Feed importer and paste it here if it's not too long maybe you just missed something.

Comment: I have added the export of feed importer configuration. Thanks for your help.